# No usb wifi adapter shows up

Tags: wireless, 17.10, adapter

I am using ubuntu 17.10. After installing driver for USB wifi adapter. I still cannot see the usb wifi adapter.

[image]

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b52b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3496 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 
802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group 
default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:7b:44:27:57:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP 
group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:f7:08:20:90:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.20.20/24 brd 172.20.20.255 scope global dynamic wlp1s0
       valid_lft 248sec preferred_lft 248sec
    inet6 fe80::c3e3:cefb:36eb:43d1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What is the exact response to the command: `sudo modprobe rtl8812au` Is Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: Secure boot is enabled. And $ sudo modprobe rtl8812au outputs nothing: `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-25-generic `. And I am on **ubuntu 17.10** @chili555

Comment: How about `sudo modprobe 8812au` ?

Comment: **sudo modprobe 8812au** outputs `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Required key not available`.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: Could you give me any insight on why this has something to do with secure boot and MOK manager? I only know step-by-step solution for keeping **virtualbox** working with secure boot enabled. And the link you sent to me is dealing with a **virtualbox issue**. Thanks!

Comment: There are some other issues on ubuntu if I disabled secure boot and that's why I need to keep virtualbox with UEFI secure boot enabled.